# Unable to import Excel file through Web

Tags: html, perl

I an new to html programming using perl-cgi and i want to import an excel file through a webpage.I am using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel Module of perl for that and the code is :

```
if($fileName) {
  my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
  my $workbook = $parser->parse($fileName);
   if ( !defined $workbook ) {
        die $parser->error(), ".\n";
    }
   for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
        my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

        for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
            for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

                my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                next unless $cell;

               # print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
                print  $cell->value() ,"|"      ;
                #print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            }
                print "\n";
        }
    }


}
```

Here fileName variable is the name of excel file i am inputting from the HTML form whose code is:

```
<form id='form1' method='GET' action='#'>
 <input id='fileSelect' name='file' type='file' accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel'>
 <input type=submit value='submit'>
 </form>
```

I have written this server side code in a directory say /a/b/c in linux and in that directory i have copied the file xyz.xls.So whenever i load the file xyz.xls through the web , i obtain the results and in case i load another file say pqr.xls which is not located in the directory /a/b/c , i have this Error File not found.But i want to import any file from a user who is using this webpage.

I am stuck here ,please suggest something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint, `die $parser->error(), ". ==>$fileName\n";`

Comment: Your directory `/a/b/c` is a really bad example. Don't create folders on the root level (starting with a slash `/`) on your Linux box. You probably did not do that and it's just an example, but it looks ilke you did.

Comment: When you add `"\n"` to a `die` in Perl, the _at foo.pl line 123_ part will be omitted. That's not very useful when you are looking for errors. Remove the newline to get better debugging output, and do as @Сухой27 suggested and include the filename. It's likely that your Perl script, being run by your webserver, does not have read permissions on the file because it's in some weird folder that Apache (or nginx?) cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

Your perl code looks OK. But your form should be

```
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

unless you make a FromData object using javascript on the client-side and send it via ajax.

Also it is not very clear how you handle the sent file on the server-side.